# Conditionally replacing elements in a list with a list in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do this

```
a <- list(1,2,3)
a[a == 2] <- list(1,2,3)
```

Which gives me `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. Generally speaking, I iteratively want to replace elements in a list of integers based on a condition with other lists of various lengths that depend on the integer in the original list.

Comment: Use `a[[2]] <- list(1,2,3)`

Comment: @MrFlick works for the simplification of my problem, but not for my real problem, edited the main quiestion

Comment: How is `a == 2` supposed to work with a nested list of lists. Maybe you should step back and say why you think such a thing is necessary. Lists can hold heterogeneous data types so doing a comparison overall of them can be problematic.

Comment: In python for example i would just do
a = [[1,2,3] for i in a if a == 2]

Comment: You could do `a[which(sapply(a, identical, 2))] <- list(list(1,2,3))`. it's not as pretty in R, that's for sure. if you are doing an iteration, then probably use `lapply` or `map` is more R-like.

Answer (score 1):

The question did not state what result is desired but this works without warning or error replacing the second element of `a` with the indicated list.

```
a <- list(1, 2, 3)
a[a == 2] <- list(list(1,2,3))
```

giving:

```
> str(a)
List of 3
 $ : num 1
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
  ..$ : num 3
 $ : num 3
```

Comment: Of course you can only run that once. Running it twice or a call like `a[a == 3] <- list(list(5, 6))` afterwords would fail.

Comment: That's a different problem but if we wanted to generalize to that then `a[sapply(a, identical, 3)] <-. list(list(1,2,3))`